# Route prefix naming restriction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple asp.net web api controller with a post method. On the top of that api controller, if I name the RoutePrefix attribute with "**sigs**", then the post action is working; POST http://localhost:7178/sigs

- If I name the RoutePrefix attribute with names such as "**signatures**", I get run-time error with '405 code method not allowed':

POST http://localhost:7178/signatures  --> returns 405 status code

- if I name the RoutePrefix attribute with names such as "**signature**", I get run-time error with '400 Bad Request':

POST http://localhost:7178/signature  --> returns 400 Bad Request

Question: I am not sure if "signatures" or "signature" are **key or reversed** word with RESTful query strings. They have a special meaning in url query strings?  I hope somebody is willing to explain that question for me. Thank you in advance.

The following codes are working OK when the RoutePrefix naming is "**signs**":

```
[RoutePrefix("sigs")]
public class SignatureApiController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ISignatureService _signatureService;

        public SignatureApiController(ISignatureService signatureService)
        {
            _signatureService = signatureService;
        }

        [Route("")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage CreateSignature(SignatureFormModel sig)
        {
            var val = _signatureService.Save(sig.ImageData, sig.ContactId);
            return val ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, new { ContactId = sig.ContactId, _signatureService.Result }) : Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, _signatureService.Result);
        }  
    }
```

However, the following codes are not working when I name the RoutePrefix with some key/reversed words (?) like "**signatures**", "**signature**":

```
[RoutePrefix("signatures")]
    // [RoutePrefix("signature")]
        // Note: RoutePrefix named "signatures" causes error '405: Method Not Allowed' ; RoutePrefix named "signature"  causes error: '400: Bad Request'
        public class SignatureApiController : ApiController
        {
            private readonly ISignatureService _signatureService;

            public SignatureApiController(ISignatureService signatureService)
            {
                _signatureService = signatureService;
            }

            [Route("")]
            [HttpPost]
            public HttpResponseMessage CreateSignature(SignatureFormModel sig)
            {
                var val = _signatureService.Save(sig.ImageData, sig.ContactId);
                return val ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, new { ContactId = sig.ContactId, _signatureService.Result }) : Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, _signatureService.Result);
            }  
        }
```